# select employee_name, count(dependent) as dependents from employee error

Tags: mysql

i have this two tables "employee table, dependent table"

the employee table has "ID, employee_id, employee_name"

the dependent table has "ID, employee_id, dependent_name, relationship"

and the value of employee table is `("1, 123, Vincent")`

and the value of dependent table is

`("1, 123, Angel, daughter")`,`("2, 123, Mary, daughter")`

how will i display an employee_id and employee_name and it's number of dependents?

like select employee_id, employee_name , count(dependent) as dependents ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 select e.employee_id,e.employee_name,count(d.employee_id) as dependents
     from department d
     inner join employee e on (e.employee_id=d.employee_id) 
     group by d.employee_id;
```

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75a30/4)

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By and Count

```
select 
   em.Employee_id, 
   count(*) 
from 
   employee em inner join 
       dependant dp on 
             em.employee_id = dp.employee_id
group by 
       em.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   e.employee_id,
   e.employee_name,
   count(select * from dependent 
         table where 
        dependent table.employee_id=employee table.employee_id) 
from 
      employee table e 
        where e.employee_id=123
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.employee_id, e.employee_name , (select count(*) from 
dependent_table where employee_id=e.employee_id) as dependents 
from employee_table as e
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its worked

```
select a.empid ,a.empname , count(b.deptname) from employee a , dependent b 
where a.empid = b.empid and b.empid=123;
```